# How does the System Status iPhone app obtain Wifi network roaming information?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, wifi, roaming

I've just downloaded an app from the App Store called System Status which gives you detailed information about the iPhone it's installed on.

One of the features provides a system log which allows you to see the network info when you roam from one BSSID to another.

My question is how did they do this?

I have searched everywhere and the only way I have found requires the use of private APIs. I am assuming that since this app is live on the App Store there is a legal way to obtain the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deeper digging I think that they got the information from the Apple Status Log, more details are available via these links:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/asl.3.html

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/accessing-the-ios-system-log/